# light, ria, domain service - service not found

Tags: silverlight, domainservices, wcf-ria-services

I have a silverlight application with two ria domain services (ado.net dataservices). Until recently I have both services in one 'WCF RIA services Class Library' and everything was working perfectly.

Yesterday we decided to spilt the services into separate libraries (breaking many references and namespaces in the process). Everything is back together and compiling again, but now when we try to run the application we're getting an error:

The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

Fiddler reveals a bit more:

HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly

/ClientBin/DisMembershipService-Web-AuthenticationService.svc/binary/GetUser

It seems to me like the services are not being generated in the clientBin folder. I'm at a loss, the service used to generate, so I must be missing something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own solution. Turns out when you have multiple WCF RIA Service Class Libraries, the website project needs reference to both, or it won't generate the service.

In turn, the main silverlight project needs reference to both client-side ria projects, otherwise the service files will generate in the main silverlight project AND in the client ria projects causing duplication errors.